# Python flask Возможно ли задать путь скрипту?

Tags: python

Появилась необходимость разбить файлы проекта (Flask) на разные папки (т.к. их стало много и они все в куче), например скрипты которые относятся к пользователю в идеале разместить в папке Profile, скрипты которые отвечают за представление страниц в Pages и так далее, после чего импортировать их при необходимости например в главном скрипте. 
Как это можно сделать? И возможно ли вообще?

Comment: Да, это возможно и подробно описано как в документации Python, так и Flask.

Comment: А ссылку не дадите?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html и http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/blueprints/

Comment: Ничего не ясно.

Comment: Можно какой-то пример? Как например из файла Main.py, сделать импорт скрипта pagesHadnler.py из папки Pages?

Comment: Уж извините, но мой прошлый ответ вы удалили вместе со своим вопросом, так что впредь я буду воздерживаться от ответов вам.